# add a postfix to a string v.getName() for a collection of strings in groovy for Jira scriptrunner

Tags: string, loops, groovy, jira-rest-api, scriptrunner-for-jira

I would like to add a postfix called "-Inbox" to each of the elements of a collection of strings. Here is my current approach:

```
def matchedVersions = issue.getFixVersions().intersect(
        newIssueproject.getVersions(), 
        Version.NAME_COMPARATOR 
    )
def mynewVersions = new ArrayList <Version> ()

 for( Version v: matchedVersions){
           Version mynewVersion= ComponentAccessor.versionManager.createVersion(v.getName()+"-Inbox", startDate, releaseDate, description, newIssueproject.id, scheduleAfterVersion, released)
           mynewVersions.add(mynewVersion)      
                
 }
```

Is there a simpler approach that I could use to avoid the loop, the action I am doing is repetitive and takes time and I would like to find a new approach. I just need to create a new varaible called `mynewVersions` which is identical to `matchedVersions` with the only difference being that the name of each version has the postfix "-Inbox" appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plain groovy with List-operations and right-currying of a `createVersion()` method:

```
def versionCreator = ComponentAccessor.versionManager.&createVersion.rcurry( startDate, releaseDate, description, newIssueproject.id, scheduleAfterVersion, released )

def mynewVersions = issue.fixVersions.intersect( newIssueproject.versions, Version.NAME_COMPARATOR ).collect{ versionCreator it.name + '-Inbox' }
```